# ionic2 API Call issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on an Android application using Ionic framework version 2. The app makes an http request to an url, gets the json and displayes the data on the screen. Its a very simple and basic application. With CORS plugin on my chrome, things went smooth. But once i build the apk and run on the device, it doesn't seem to work. I have followed all the suggestions provided in various URL's for the cordova whitelist plugin. But nothing seem to resolve my issue and it is very annoying. Things i did on my end

Step1:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

Step2:
cordova prepare

config.xml

index.html

While executing the step 1, i got an error unexpected token. But i could see the plugin files are added in the project. Could that be a proble?

In the App Debug log i see this - 
SystemWebViewClient: URL blocked by whitelist: http://.com

Comment: Show us some code and post the full errormessage. We can't debug something we can't see

Comment: The issue got resolved. The fetch.json file under the plugins folder was somehow corrupted and full of null values. I fixed the file and rebuild it. The whilelist settings got recognized and working fine :).